# linq, I have no idea what I'm doing

Tags: vb.net, linq

LINQ novice here, go easy on me.

I've added another table to the below query: (Join c2 In objGlobalDataContext.ActivityStatuses On c2.Activity_Status_ID Equals c.Status_ID)

I want to get a status field back (c2.status_name), but since the reference has nulls (c.Status_ID) I'm not getting any results.

Can someone help? easy points!

Thanks in advance..

```
    Dim objAdminActivity = (From c In objGlobalDataContext.Activities
                            Join c1 In objGlobalDataContext.ActivityTypes On c1.Activity_Type_ID Equals c.Activity_Type_ID
                            Join c2 In objGlobalDataContext.ActivityStatuses On c2.Activity_Status_ID Equals c.Status_ID
                            Order By c.Activity_Name.Trim()
                            Where c.Is_Reserved_Activity = False
                            Select c.Activity_Auto_ID, c.Activity_Name, c1.Activity_Type_Description,
                                c.Active, c.Activity_Number, c.Effective_From_Date, c.Effective_To_Date,
                                c2.Status_Name, c.Automatically_Created, c.Costed_Activity).ToArray()
```

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing, how should we?

Comment: How is that useful lol

Comment: I suspect that you need to make use of the `DefaultIfEmpty` method. I say suspect because I haven't examined your situation carefully but if the issue is nulls in a join then it sounds like you want to create an outer join and that requires `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney ...
I've had a look at that path but can't get the syntax correct. Will keep looking.

Comment: How do you expect to get a status field (`c2.status_name`) back when the `Status_ID` is null? Or do you just want a null value there when `Status_ID` is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a null `Status_Name` when there is no matching `Status_ID` or `Status_ID` is null, you can use a left join:

```
Dim objAdminActivity = (From c In objGlobalDataContext.Activities
                        Join c1 In objGlobalDataContext.ActivityTypes On c1.Activity_Type_ID Equals c.Activity_Type_ID
                        Group Join c2 In objGlobalDataContext.ActivityStatuses On c2.Activity_Status_ID Equals c.Status_ID Into Group
                        From c2 in Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        Order By c.Activity_Name.Trim()
                        Where c.Is_Reserved_Activity = False
                        Select c.Activity_Auto_ID, c.Activity_Name, c1.Activity_Type_Description,
                            c.Active, c.Activity_Number, c.Effective_From_Date, c.Effective_To_Date,
                            c2.Status_Name, c.Automatically_Created, c.Costed_Activity).ToArray()
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was after, bravo!